# INSERT from memory to SQL inefficient

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

So I have been trying to optimize a situation. Essentially, I have a WEB API service that queries a SQL Server Database and then inserts it into a SQLite database on a client machine.

After running some tests. I found that it took 0.50% of the time to load the data from SQL Server into an array of objects in C# and the insert to all of the other time.

Is my insert incredibly inefficient?

Here is my method:

```
public void addDataToTable()
{
    using (SQLiteConnection SQLconn = new SQLiteConnection(SQLiteConnectionString))
    {
        SQLconn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = SQLconn.CreateCommand();
        foreach (Step row in allSteps)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Step (StepID, EWPID, StepNum, Description, MTOQty, ToDateQty, CraftCode, OriginPkg, SF01, SF10, Updated) VALUES " + 
                "(@param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5, @param6, @param7, @param8, @param9, @param10, @param11);";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param1", row.StepID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param2", row.EWPID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param3", row.StepNum));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param4", row.Description));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param5", row.MTOQty));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param6", row.ToDateQty));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param7", row.CraftCode));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param8", row.OriginPkg));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param9", row.SF01));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param10", row.SF10));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param11", row.Updated));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

allSteps is an array of objects that coincides with the columns from SQL I'm getting:

```
public class Step
{
    public int StepID { get; set; }
    public int EWPID { get; set; }
    public int StepNum { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double MTOQty { get; set; }
    public double ToDateQty { get; set; }
    public string CraftCode { get; set; }
    public string OriginPkg { get; set; }
    public string SF01 { get; set; }
    public string SF10 { get; set; }
    public string Updated { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to dump an entire Select statement into a SQLite table without the looping?

Comment: For every step you add the parameters (even if they already exist). Add the parameters once and set the value within the loop. Also use a transaction scope so that all inserts are within the same transaction or you'll get penalised (unless you need each insert to be atomic).

Comment: This [post](http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/make-your-sqlite-bulk-inserts-very-fast-in-c/) recommends that you use a transaction then commit all of the statements at once.

Comment: @Lloyd I see what you mean. How do you change the values of the parameters after they have been added to the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite rough and might have some mistakes, but you get the idea:

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(SQLiteConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

        SQLiteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Step (StepID, EWPID, StepNum, Description, MTOQty, ToDateQty, CraftCode, OriginPkg, SF01, SF10, Updated) VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5, @param6, @param7, @param8, @param9, @param10, @param11); ";

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param1"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param2"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param3"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param4"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param5"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param6"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param7"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param8"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param9"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param10"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param11"));

        foreach (Step row in allSteps)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@param1"].Value = row.StepID;
            cmd.Parameters["@param2"].Value = row.EWPID;
            cmd.Parameters["@param3"].Value = row.StepNum;
            cmd.Parameters["@param4"].Value = row.Description;
            cmd.Parameters["@param5"].Value = row.MTOQty;
            cmd.Parameters["@param6"].Value = row.ToDateQty;
            cmd.Parameters["@param7"].Value = row.CraftCode;
            cmd.Parameters["@param8"].Value = row.OriginPkg;
            cmd.Parameters["@param9"].Value = row.SF01;
            cmd.Parameters["@param10"].Value = row.SF10;
            cmd.Parameters["@param11"].Value = row.Updated;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
```